# How to get rid of «POST net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET» error?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, push, zeromq

I am making a chat on php Ratchet and I have difficulties with [push tutorial](http://socketo.me/docs/push)

I am sending user message to send_message.php and there is a mistake: "POST work-fox/send_message.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

chat.js:

```
var panel = document.querySelector('.panel');
var message = document.querySelector('.message');
var start_dialog = document.querySelector('#start_dialog');
var send_msg = document.querySelector('#send_msg');
var chatId = '1';  

var conn = new ab.Session('ws://localhost:8443',
    function() {
    conn.subscribe(chatId, function(topic, data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    },
    function() {
        console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
    },
    {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
);

send_msg.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('message', message.value); 
    xhr.open("POST", "send_message.php", true);
    xhr.send(form);
    xhr.onload = function(e) { 
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}
```

send_message.php:

```
$entryData = array(
    'fromId' => '1',
    'message' => $_POST['message'],
    'toId' => '2'
);

$context = new ZMQContext();
$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
$socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
$socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
```

The error, as I understand it, lies in this line: `$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher')` 
Please tell me how to solve my problem